# Openshift Jenkins configuring for a Visual studio project

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, openshift

I'm working on configuring **Jenkins** in **Openshift** for a **visual Studio project**.
I need to set the **MSBuild path**.
Can anyone tell me the value for that or a workaround?

[image: Issue]

Here is a reference i used.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878203/Integrate-Jenkins-with-MSBuild-and-NuGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift Online does not run Window, nor does it support running Windows executables (*.exe files).  OpenShift will also not support running a .NET project on it, which is what it looks like you are trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure he said Openshift Online, however Openshift can run dotnet core applications on Openshift.